# AppendAllText producing invalid JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I have a `JSON` file containing:

```
[{
    "title":"Colors",
    "text":"1. White 2. Blue 3. Red 4. Yellow 5. Green"
}]
```

If I use

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(favecolors, Formatting.Indented);
var jsonFile= Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/favecolors.json");
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@jsonFile, ","+json);
```

I can append a JSON object to the file resulting in:

```
[{
    "title":"Colors",
    "text":"1. White 2. Blue 3. Red 4. Yellow 5. Green"
}],{
    "title":"Colors",
    "text":"1. White 2. Blue 3. Red 4. Yellow 5. Green"
}
```

which isn't valid JSON because the right square bracket is in the wrong place. Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the json of your file is going to be always the same, in that case a json array with at least one node `[{},{}]` you could do that

```
var jsonFile = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/favecolors.json");
FileStream fs = new FileStream(@jsonFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite);
fs.SetLength(fs.Length - 1); // Remove the last symbol ']'
fs.Close();
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(favecolors, Formatting.Indented);
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@jsonFile, "," + json + "]");
```

It is not the most elegant solution but it should make that you want to do.

Note: this solution is very tricky, be sure that the content of your file ends with the ']' symbol, otherwise you would rather do the following: 1) Read the file into a var, 2) concat the new json (fitting it properly), 3) write the file with the merged json.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something more generic, instead of adding/removing the ending bracket. Hope the following example fits your needs.

```
[JsonObject]
public class FavoriteColor
{
    public FavoriteColor()
    {}

    public FavoriteColor(string title, string text)
    {
        Title = title;
        Text = text;
    }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "title")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    // Append new objects to your file
    private async Task Append()
    {
        // Read file content and deserialize
        string content = await ReadAsync("json.txt");

        var colors = new List<FavoriteColor>();
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(content))
            colors.AddRange(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<FavoriteColor>>(content));

        // Add your new favorite color!
        var fav = new FavoriteColor("new", "new color");
        colors.Add(fav);

        // Writo back to file
        await WriteAsync("json.txt", JsonConvert.SerializeObject(colors));
    }

    // Async read
    private async Task<string> ReadAsync(string file)
    {
        if (!File.Exists(file))
            return null;

        string content;
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(file))
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[fileStream.Length];
            await fileStream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, (int)fileStream.Length);
            content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
        }
        return content;
    }

    // Async write
    private async Task WriteAsync(string file, string content)
    {
        using (var fileStream = File.OpenWrite(file))
        {
            byte[] buffer = (new UTF8Encoding()).GetBytes(content);
            await fileStream.WriteAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        }
    }
}
```